# Pushwoosh and iOs certificates - Multiple apps

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, phonegap-build, pushwoosh

im having a big doubt here, and i couldn't find any answer over the internet.

We develop multiple ios apps, under phonegap build, apps are similiar, just logo image change and some internal parameters.

In the process of publish one app, we generate an ios certificate for distribution, then generate the mp , and register the app on pushwoosh.

Now we get adviced than no more certificates are avaible to distribution for ios, so the only way to continue doing this is to use a same distribution certificate for multiple apps.

Is this possible, considering we are using pushwoosh for pushes?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A push certificate cannot be used for more than one app.
Every app has a unique app id and push certificates are for one specific app id only.

Distribution certificates are not linked to an app, there is one per Apple account, why are you even trying to generate and use more than one?

Maybe you are confusing a distribution certificate with a distribution profile, a distribution profile is linked to a specific app.You should defiantly have multiple distribution profiles.

Comment: Thanks for your help. As i posted this question, i tried to publish another app with same distribution certificate, and it worked ok. I didnt know how apple handle this certificates, and pushwoosh generates one by they own, so i get confused with so many steps. Thanks again, now is pretty clear.